# How to create a radio component in Angular that works with reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a list of values that look like this:

```
export interface MyValueListModel {
  values: MyValueModel[];
}
export interface MyValueModel {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

And I have 2 components, the first, is where the the form gets submitted, and the child is the radio component, and I'm generating as many children as the number of values I have:

```
<radio-list>
  <radio-component *ngFor="let valueControl of values.controls" [controlAttribute]="valueControl">
  </radio-component>
</radio-list>
```

The problem with this approach is that every radio input has a different control, which means even if I set the name attribute to be the same, the controls still behave like checkboxes, even though the view still behaves like a radio (i.e. only selected item is shown as selected). I'm kinda lost on the best way solve this, so I would appreciate some help.

Update:

Thanks to [Corné](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9678462/corn%C3%A9) pointing it out, I checked the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/radio/radio.ts) of Angular's Material radio components, and they basically have an attribute in the List/Group Model that updates with the current radio value whenever the inputs change. So if I wanted to do something similar, I'd have to change my data structure like this:

```
export interface MyValueListModel {
  values: MyValueModel[];
  value: MyValueModel; //new
}
export interface MyValueModel {
  id: string; 
  title: string;
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

This sounds like a decent solution and I'll probably use it if I have no better alternative for my use case, but if someone can suggest another solution that would utilize reactive form's native functionalities specifically then that'd be great.

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples

Comment: I just checked the source code, they're adding the value in the list model as a separate attribute and updating it whenever the radio input changed. I'm gonna update the OP later, thanks.